How can I implement the Oauth with aws amplify in js code to get the access tokens?
I created a react application with aws authentication,
import { Amplify } from "aws-amplify";
import awsmobile from "../aws-exports";
import { Authenticator, Flex } from "@aws-amplify/ui-react"


Amplify.configure(awsmobile)

const Login = () => {
    return (




            <div>
                <Authenticator>
                    {({ signOut, user }) => (
                        <div className="App">
                            <p onClick={() => { }}>
                                Hey {user.username}, welcome to my channel, with auth!
                            </p>
                            <button onClick={signOut}>Sign out</button>
                        </div>
                    )}
                </Authenticator>
            </div>

    )
}

my requirement is to develop the other application and with oauth, i need access tokens from this application cognito
please give me a solution for this

This is the example:
import { fetchAuthSession } from 'aws-amplify/auth';

async function currentSession() {
  try {
    const { accessToken, idToken } = (await fetchAuthSession()).tokens ?? {};
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

More details from Amplify's official documentation: Manage user session and credentials

if i store these accessToken and IdToken,
after signOut, how can i signIn with  accessToken and IdToken , without email & password,
can you please tell me
